# Extract metadata from a picture with exiftool into a json object

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm developing a website where I need to extract the metadata of an image (jpeg) with exiftool. I'm doing it with this code:

```
$cmd = exec("exiftool ".$this->url, $result);
```

`$result` is now a classic array:

```
array (size=113)
0 => string 'ExifTool Version Number         : 10.40' (length=39)
1 => string 'File Name                       : photo7.jpg' (length=44)
2 => string 'Directory                       : images' (length=40)
3 => string 'File Size                       : 139 kB' (length=40)
4 => string 'File Modification Date/Time     : 2017:11:26 16:27:05+01:00' (length=59)
5 => string 'File Access Date/Time           : 2017:12:17 23:07:18+01:00' (length=59)
6 => string 'File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2017:11:26 16:27:05+01:00' (length=59)
7 => string 'File Permissions                : rw-r--r--' (length=43)
8 => string 'File Type                       : JPEG' (length=38)
9 => string 'File Type Extension             : jpg' (length=37)
...
```

But I want to turn this array into an other array with meaningful keys and not numbers. Something even better would be to have a json object. In any case, I want the final array to looks like this:

```
    array (size=113)
'ExifTool Version Number' => string '10.40' (length=5)
'File Name' => string 'photo7.jpg' (length=10)
...
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just split the strings at the colon...

```
$result2 = array();
foreach($result as $value){
    $tmp = preg_split("#\s*\:\s*#", $value);
    $result2[$tmp[0]] = $tmp[1];
}
$result = result2;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach is just using the **`-json` option** of `exiftool`. Which returns a JSON list of images and their attributes:

```
[{
  "SourceFile": "img/mural.jpeg",
  "ExifToolVersion": 10.60,
  …
```

Thus you can simply [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode)`(`[`implode`](http://php.net/implode)`(` `$result` `))`